Issue with image rotation in konvajs
I have a konvajs rectangle with some text inside it and when text is double clicked I am creating a content editable div with editable text. when the blur event of the div is called, i am creating a konvajs image and adding it to the rectangle. I have modified the solution mentioned below as per my requirement.
Rich text editing features 
However, when i rotate the group and edit it, the image rendered has improper rotation. Please find my fiddle.
Jsfiddle
function onDblClick(ev, stage, shape, textNode, group, tr, image) {
  textNode.hide();
  tr.hide();
  if (image != null) {
    image.hide();
  }
  var attrs = shape.getAttrs();
  var shapeId = attrs['id'];
  console.log('attrs', attrs);

  var textPosition = shape.absolutePosition();
  var areaPosition = {
    x: stage.container().offsetLeft + textPosition.x,
    y: stage.container().offsetTop + textPosition.y,
  };
  var textarea = document.createElement('div');
  document.body.appendChild(textarea);
  textarea.setAttribute('contenteditable', 'true');
  textarea.setAttribute('id', 'editable-text');

  // apply many styles to match text on canvas as close as possible
  // remember that text rendering on canvas and on the textarea can be different
  // and sometimes it is hard to make it 100% the same. But we will try...
  textarea.innerHTML = 'get text value from object';
  textarea.style.position = 'absolute';
  textarea.style.top = areaPosition.y + 'px';
  textarea.style.left = areaPosition.x + 'px';
  //textarea.style.width = shape.width() - shape.padding() * 2 + 'px';
  //textarea.style.height = shape.height() - shape.padding() * 2 + 5 + 'px';
  textarea.style.fontSize = '12px'; //set globally
  textarea.style.border = 'none';
  textarea.style.padding = '0px';
  textarea.style.margin = '0px';
  textarea.style.overflow = 'hidden';
  textarea.style.background = 'none';
  textarea.style.outline = 'none';
  textarea.style.resize = 'none';
  //textarea.style.lineHeight = `${textNode.lineHeight()}`;
  //textarea.style.fontFamily = textNode.fontFamily();
  textarea.style.transformOrigin = 'left top';
  var rotation = group.rotation();

  var transform = '';
  if (rotation) {
    transform += 'rotateZ(' + rotation + 'deg)';
  }
  var px = 0;
  var isFirefox = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') > -1;
  if (isFirefox) {
    px += 2 + Math.round(textNode.fontSize() / 20);
  }
  transform += 'translateY(-' + px + 'px)';

  textarea.style.transform = transform;

  var shapeAttr = shape.getAttrs();
  console.log('shapeAttr', shapeAttr);
  var shapeWidth = shapeAttr['width'];
  var shapeHeight = shapeAttr['height'];
  var shapeOffsetLeft = shapeAttr['x'];
  var shapeOffsetTop = shapeAttr['y'];

  function renderText() {
    // convert DOM into image
    html2canvas(document.querySelector('#editable-text'), {
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
    }).then((canvas) => {
      // show it inside Konva.Image
      if (image == null) {
        const img = new Konva.Image({
          x: shapeOffsetLeft,
          y: shapeOffsetTop,
          draggable: false,
          scaleX: 1 / window.devicePixelRatio,
          scaleY: 1 / window.devicePixelRatio,
          //rotation:rotation
          // width:shapeWidth,
          //height:shapeHeight
        });
        img.image(canvas);
        //img.rotate(rotation);
        group.add(img);
        textarea.remove();
        tr.show();
        img.on('dblclick ', (ev) =>
          onDblClick(ev, stage, shape, textNode, group, tr, img)
        );
      } else {
        image.image(canvas);
        image.show();
        textarea.remove();
        tr.show();
      }
    });
  }

please let me know your thoughts on this and help to fix this.
